# Maximum count of same digit in array list

Tags: java, collections

Suppose I have an array list of of values {0,1,1,0,1,1,1}
Here the maximum repeat of value 1 in continuous sequence is 3.
How do I find the maximum count.

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter value");
    x = in.nextLine();

      list.add(""+x);
}

Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();

for (String word : list) {
    Integer count = countMap.get(word);
    if(count == null) {
        count = 0;
    }
    countMap.put(word, (count.intValue()+1));
}
```

This gives total count of same value but I need maximum continuous values.

Comment: Step1: Detect a continuous sequence. Step 2: When the seqeuence ends, compare with current stored value to see if the new sequence is of greater length

Comment: Can you help with some code syntax so that I can move forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
     InputStreamReader r=new InputStreamReader(System.in);  
     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r);  


     for (int i=0;i<15;i++)
     {
         System.out.println("Enter value");
         String x=br.readLine();
         list.add(x);
     }

LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> lhm=new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

for(String str1:list){
    int flag=0;
    for(Entry<String, Integer> entry:lhm.entrySet()){   

        if(entry.getKey().equals(str1)){
            flag=1;
            break;
        }}
        if(flag==0){
            lhm.put(str1, 1);
        }


}

int maxCount = 1;
int currCount = 1;
for (int i=1;i<list.size();++i) {
  if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i-1))) {
    ++currCount;
    if(list.size()==i+1){
        maxCount = Math.max(lhm.get(list.get(i)), currCount); 
      lhm.put(list.get(i), maxCount);
    }
  } else {
      maxCount = Math.max(lhm.get(list.get(i-1)), currCount); 
      lhm.put(list.get(i-1), maxCount);
    currCount = 1;
  }

}


for(Entry<String, Integer> entry:lhm.entrySet()){
    System.out.println("Maximum Sequential occurrence of element- "+entry.getKey()+" is- "+entry.getValue());//display result
}


}
```

Above code will print max sequential occurrence of all element in list.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
// Initialize to 1 because first element is equal to itself.
int maxCount = 1;
int currCount = 1;
for (int i=1;i<list.size();++i) {
  if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i-1))) {
    ++currCount;
  } else {
    currCount = 1;
  }
  maxCount = Math.max(maxCount, currCount);
}
return maxCount;
```

This iterates over your sequence and finds the longest continuous sequence.

Comment: it is taking value from index 1,not 0.
If I add all elements as {1,1,1,1,1}
it returns 4,not 5.
and if I add,{1,1,1,0,0,1,1} it returns 2.

Comment: It is starting at 1 because I access the list at the i-1st index.

Comment: Thank you, I manually updated,
  if(list.get(0)==1)
   maxCount=maxCount+1;
 and got with right solution.
Thanks for the solution.